# Ambiguous error in xpath [last()] method

Tags: css, regex, xpath, cucumber, capybara

In a custom step in cucumber, I wrote this:

```
find(:xpath ,"//ul//input[@placeholder = 'Enter Something'][last()]").set(value)
```

And Im getting Regexp ambiguous match error:It is getting both the elements.
How can I get this element using `xpath`(or maybe even `css`) in cucumber??

I'm using `cucumber-1.2.1` and `capybara-2.0.3`

(Please note:every attribute in the above two input fields are same)

HTML:

```
<ul class = "someclass">
  <li>
   <div>
     <a></a>
       <input></input>
       <input placeholder = "Enter Something"></input>
   </div>
   </li>   
 <li>
   <div>
     <a></a>
       <input></input>
       <input placeholder = "Enter Something"> // This is the element I want 
       </input>
   </div>
   </li>   
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an extra set of parenthesis in your xpath:

```
"(//ul//input[@placeholder = 'Enter Something'])[last()]"
```

Comment: Perfect!! I am new to xpath so can u just explain what the parenthesis implies?

Comment: This isn't a particularly technical explanation, but AFAIK `//ul//input[@placeholder = 'Enter Something'][last()]` means "find the last input with the attribute below **each** `ul`", whereas the parenthesis means "get all the matching inputs across all `ul`s and then find the last one" Small but subtle :)

Comment: And is there any way to get the first element??

Comment: `[position()=1]` which can be abbreviated to [1] - xpath is [1 based indexed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-position)